# Terminate While Loop scanf("%c",&ch)

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I want to read in an input one character at a time. I don't know how big this input will be, so I'm not pointing an array to the input, but rather processing each character one at a time and constructing a linked list. The problem I'm having though, is how do I terminate this while loop after the last character has been read?

```
struct node{
struct node *next;
int data;
};

int main(){

int i; //iterator
char ch;
//char *numberArr = (char*)malloc(1024,sizeof(char*));
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* curr = NULL;
struct node* tail = NULL;


printf("Please input a number: ");
while (((scanf(" %c",&ch)) != -1)){
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```

Comment: `while (((scanf(" %c",&ch)) == 1)` - What is your problem? And comparing with `-1` is wrong anyway! Read the man page of the function.

Comment: What do you type after the "last" character?  Do you wait, hit <Enter> or some key(s) to cause end-of-file?

Comment: well what I'd like to do is scanf(" %c",&c) and the input is going to be a really large number input so 3143143124132543125, and once that last 5 is read in I'd like to cancel out of the while loop. Because once the characters are read in, it hangs in the while loop.

Comment: @user3260745 How should the program know that's the last 5? What if you keep typing 638961 after that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read all characters, including whitespace characters, use:

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
{
   // Use c as a char.
}
```

If you want to skip whitespace characters, use:

```
char c;
while ( scanf(" %c", &c) == 1 )
{
   // Use c.
}
```

Notice the use of `int` vs `char` as the type for `c` in the two cases.

Comment: so all my characters are being read. The only thing is that I would like the while loop to terminate once everything has been read, the while loop terminates and the program closes. my input should terminate with a '\n' character but even (((scanf(" %c",&ch)) != '\n')) won't terminate on a new line.

Comment: @user3260745, that's correct. You'll have to terminate that by sending EOF to the stream. On a unix terminal, that is usually Ctrl+D and an a windows cmd window, it is usually Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Okay, I actually figured it out! I guess when scanf is done reading from an input it returns an integer < 0, so != -1 wouldn't always work as it doesn't return -1 specifically.

Comment: @user3260745, you should be able to use `!= EOF`. `scanf` should return *Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.*

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually figured it out! I guess when scanf is done reading from an input it returns an integer < 0, so != -1 wouldn't always work as it doesn't return -1 specifically.

ref:
ben glasser answer on this post:
[scanf() in while loop not terminating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549102/scanf-in-while-loop-not-terminating)

Answer (score 0):

After the successful completion of scanf function it will a non-zero value(value>0). And if there occures any problem then it will return 0.I think in none of the case you will get a -1.So if you want to terminate the loop you can prompt the user to give a special character that can signify the end of input.Or if you are reading it from a file then you can use the EOF to terminate the loop.

Hope you will like the solution....

If anyone finds any mistakes in my answer than please comment it below.
I will be very thankful to him.